# Swift : Get tableView indextPath/textLabel from selected UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a tableView and inside I have UIImage , UILabel and FloatRatingView. 
FloatRatingView is a UIView , a star rating where you can rate 1-5.
So the tableView has multiple cells , and I want to get the movie title when I press FloatRatingView.

FloatRatingView has two delegate methods.

```
    func floatRatingView(ratingView: FloatRatingView, didUpdate rating: Float) {
    }
    func floatRatingView(ratingView: FloatRatingView, isUpdating rating: Float) {

    }
```

So far in my custom TableCell I have :

```
var delegate: FloatRatingViewDelegate?
 @IBOutlet weak var userRating: FloatRatingView!{
        didSet {
            if userRating.rating>0 {
            self.delegate!.floatRatingView(userRating, didUpdate: userRating.rating)
        }}
    }
```

and In the TableViewController :

```
class MoviesViewController: PFQueryTableViewController ,FloatRatingViewDelegate {



func floatRatingView(ratingView: FloatRatingView, isUpdating rating: Float) {
        print("is updating")

    }
    func floatRatingView(ratingView: FloatRatingView, didUpdate rating: Float) {
        print("did update")
    }
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        let cellIdentifier:String = "cell"

        var cell:TableCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? TableCell

        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = TableCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
        cell?.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming that the `FloatRatingView` is inside the cell, the easiest methods are to either:

- Add a delegate protocol to your cell class, implement `FloatRatingViewDelegate` in the class, and forward the callbacks to the cell delegate. Implement the cell delegate in your view controller.
- Expose your cell class's `FloatRatingView` property, and set its delegate directly to the view controller (which will need to implement `FloatRatingViewDelegate`). Iterate over the visible cells, and find which one the float rating view is in.

However, a more modern solution would be:

- Replace the delegate protocol with function properties (`var didUpdate: (Float -> Void)?`), set those in the view controller when dequeuing your cell. There, you can directly close over the `indexPath` reference.

This will result in less code overall.

Comment: how do I forward the callbacks to the cell delegate ?

Comment: I updated my code , but it seems I am missing the logic behind it